# Location based app using Little Fluffy Location Library

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am creating a location app that requires user location to be updated to my server on the move. I would like to use Little Fluffy Location library for this situation.

To understand the process:

1. Can somebody tell what will happen when I switch of GPS/Network service in my phone - will fluffy location library handle this situation? Or do I need to handle this manually in my APP?
2. In the example given in their site: https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

They register location library to call every 1 minute.

What will happen if just use:

```
 LocationLibrary.initialiseLibrary(getBaseContext(), "mypackagename");
```

Will it receive lat/long when ever the location is changed automatically? Also they claim it battery saver too? update location frequently wont the battery die?

3.I would like to know will it take location based on GPS or Network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download library project and client side project that is given on your given link. I hope you will get your answer.

1. Run client side project in android eclipse and install android apk in your phone and then check yourself for switching off GPS/Network.
2. Use refresh() to get latest location and locationInfo.lastLat for lattitude and locationInfo.lastLong for longitude.
3. It selects best provider.
4. Yeah it consumes battery power more than simple application because we are getting location.

You will get all answer if you download projects. I just downloaded projects and now i will start work on it.